# Compiling Vaadin project with Ant.

Tags: ant, compilation, vaadin7

I am new to vaadin and I have to compile my vaadin project which has .aj and .java files with circular dependencies. When I compiled with ant, I get an error indicating/related to circular dependencies. So can pl someone guide to compile my project?

Answer (score 0):

I just used maven to fix my problem. Its working for me.

Visit this link for more details [maven commands and details](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)